# Can I get GROUP_CONCAT with COUNT() on multiple columns from the same table?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE entries(
  `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `level` INT UNSIGNED,
  `type` CHAR(2),
  `attribute` INT UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

From this table, I'm currently doing the same query for 3 different columns:

```
SELECT level, COUNT(*) FROM entries GROUP BY level;
SELECT type, COUNT(*) FROM entries GROUP BY type;
SELECT attribute, COUNT(*) FROM entries GROUP BY attribute;
```

I know I can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get the `DISTINCT` entries for each of these in a single SQL call:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT level) AS levels, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT type) AS types, GROUP_CONCAT(attribute) AS attributes FROM entries;
```

But can I manipulate this query to include the counts? OR is there a different way that I can get the distinct values and counts for these columns in a single call?

EDIT: here's some data to add to the table

```
INSERT INTO entries (level, type, attribute) VALUES (1, 'VA', 5), (1, 'CD', NULL), (NULL, 'VA', 3), (NULL, 'CD', NULL), (1, 'VA', 1);
```

And the sample output

```
LEVELS   LEVEL_COUNTS  TYPES  TYPES_COUNTS  ATTRIBUTES    ATTRIBUTES_COUNTS
1        3             VA,CD  3,2           5,3,1         1,1,1
```

Comment: Could you supply sample data with desired results?  Having a hard time understanding what your results should be.

Comment: Sure! I added it on the post, but here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ea92/3)

Comment: @user3258505 Have a look at my solution... provides exactly your output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query. The only things remaining are to add some column aliases, and to maybe add a condition to ignore rows where there is NULL.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lvlCount.level) as LEVELS,
          GROUP_CONCAT(lvlCount.cnt) as LEVELS_COUNTS
   FROM
     (SELECT LEVEL,
             COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM entries where NOT(LEVEL IS NULL)
      GROUP BY LEVEL 
      ORDER BY LEVEL DESC) AS lvlCount) AS LEVEL,

  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(typeCount.type) as TYPES,
          GROUP_CONCAT(typeCount.cnt) as TYPES_COUNTS
   FROM
     (SELECT TYPE,
             COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM entries where NOT(TYPE IS NULL)
      GROUP BY TYPE
      ORDER BY TYPE DESC) AS typeCount) AS TYPE,

  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(attrCount.attribute) as ATTRIBUTES,
          GROUP_CONCAT(attrCount.cnt) as ATTRIBUTES_COUNTS
   FROM
     (SELECT attribute,
             COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM entries where NOT(attribute IS NULL)
      GROUP BY attribute
      ORDER BY attribute DESC) AS attrCount) AS attribute;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ea92/44